# postMessage ArrayBuffer to native client module from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-nativeclient

I would like to send HTML canvas's image to NaCl module on Google Chrome.
On "dom side", I have following code:

```
var NaClModule = .... // NaCl module denoted by <embed> tag
var canvas = .... // canvas element
canvas.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var imageData = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    NaClModule.postMessage(imageData.data);
});
```

`imageData.data` is of type `Uint8ClampedArray` on JavaScript console.
So I supposed that NaCl module see passed data as `pp::VarArrayBuffer`

However, NaCl module actually take passed data as `pp::VarDictionary`
with key = original array's index and value = original array's value
(confirmed by `pp::Var::DebugString`).

Is this expected behavior?
If not, what is worong with my code?

Or, is there any other way to pass image to NaCl module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing a canvas to a NaCl module is done in the earth example to load a texture from a jpeg (see examples/demo/earth in the SDK).

Here is a snippet from that example:

```
var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
// Send NaCl module the raw image data obtained from canvas.
common.naclModule.postMessage({'message' : 'texture',
                               'name' : name,
                               'width' : img.width,
                               'height' : img.height,
                               'data' : imageData.data.buffer});
```

So it looks like you just need to change your code to this:

```
NaClModule.postMessage(imageData.data.buffer);
```

And it should work.